# Configurable "Ingress filter" to prevent Grafana Loki for storing log item

Tags: grafana

I'm currently setting up a stack with `Grafana` and `Grafana Loki` to store, query, and analyze logs from different web applications. Most applications run on .NET using Serilog and the `Serilog.Sinks.Grafana.Loki`-Sink.

From time to time we see errors och warnings in the logs that we know are not relevant or that we want to ignore.

I know there are several options here but none of them are "straightforward":

**1. Filtering them in the reporting web app so that they are never sent to Loki**

This would require a release of the app just to filter out logs. Does not make sense to me.

**2. Filter using [LogQL](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/)**

In this case the data is still stored in Loki and it would also make my queries complicated - would be really hard to make sure all dashboards uses them same filtering logic.

**3. Filter using loki-configuration**
There seems to be some kind of `pre_ingesters`-setting in the Loki configuration but using this would probably require a restart of the Loki-service which is not a great option.

I'm basically looking for something where I (as the user) can create a number of filters (preferably using a web UI) that would be applied before Loki store the log lines, like some kind of proxy-layer.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion (disclaimer: have not tried to do what you are trying to accomplish)...see if Caddy request matchers might help:
https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/matchers

Example of configuring Loki to run with Caddy (in this case, to support TLS):
https://github.com/mikequentel/caddy-and-loki-deployment-example